# Way to keep the variable in the WebService without it resetting?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a string variable in Web Service, its not in a [WebMethod].

```
string emailAddress;
```

I am using it to store an email address, which goes fine but when I return to the website from the Web Service and then I go back to the Web Service, to use the variable, I think that the variable I changed has been reset to its original value of nothing. Is there maybe a way around this.

P.S. I am quite new to WebService and this is the first time I am trying using it.

Thanx

Comment: can you confirm if the email was an input field from the first web method? Als can you explain how many user will use this web method at once?

Comment: and include some more information about your webservice, like include the web.config file so people can see how it's suposed to work.

Comment: The email came from a txtbox that was passed to a LogIn [web method] from the web site. In that method is when I give the variable the value. Only one user will be using it at once.

Answer (score 0):

Web service methods should be considered static methods. Which means that it will not retain any state information. Ie setting a field value.

if the case is that 1 user will use the webservice, the easiest way to retain the value is to make the variables static like so:

```
static string emailAddress;
```

however, if more users will use the webservice, this solution will not work for you. You might want to consider something along the lines that is provided below:

```
// web service class
private static Dictionary<Guid, SessionObject> UserSessions = new Dictionary<Guid, SessionObject>();
private static object SessionLock = new object();

// session initialize method:
[WebMethod]
public Guid CreateNewUserSession()
{
     SessionObject userobject = new SessionObject();
     Guid SessionGuid = Guid.New();
     lock(SessionLock)
     {
         UserSessions.Add(SessionGuid, userobject);
     }
     return SessionGuid;
}

// set the email address    
[WebMethod]
public bool SetSessionEmail(Guid SessionGuid, string emailaddress)
{
     SessionObject temp;
     Lock(SessionLock)
     {
         if(!UserSessions.TryGetValue(SessionGuid, out temp))
         {
              return false;
         }
     }
     temp.EmailAddress = emailaddress;
     return true;
}

// sessionobject 
public class SessionObject
{
     public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
}
```

The given example will only work if the webservice is very basic. ie, its not refreshed or rebooted a lot, and it's not part of multiple webservices where each web call is assigned a random webservice. For simple functionality this should work. For more complex functionality you should be looking towards storing any session in a database

reading about the [app pool recycle](https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/10307/understanding-application-pool-recycling-and-how-to-fine-tune-for-use-with-outsys/) might help a bit in understanding webservices

Comment: Problem with this is that any worker process restart deletes all sessions.

Comment: worker processes are usually restarted at a set time, by default every 29 hours i think. Assuming that this is set at a fixed time like midnight, the reset should not interfere

Comment: those are exceptional circumstances

Comment: Deployments are common.; Your approach is basically fine, I'm not contradicting that. It's just that it will not be acceptable to *most* use cases. Btw, this requires session to machine affinity as well which can be a dealbreaker, too.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean with the later?

Comment: OK, so there might be many machines in a server farm behind a load balancer. When users requests are assigned randomly they will hit a random `UserSessions` object on a random node.

Comment: in that situation my solution would indeed not work at all